# Page slide up animation not working on Safari

Tags: jquery, cross-browser

I was working on this demo here: https://codyhouse.co/gem/expandable-project-presentation/

I have tried this demo and run it on my Firefox and Google Chrome and it works perfectly however on Safari whenever I scroll down it immediately scrolls back up. I have tracked down the JS code responsible for this but I do not know how to fix it:

```
$('.projects-container .cd-scroll').on('click', function(){
        $('.projects-container').animate({'scrollTop':$(window).height()}, 500); 
    });
```

I think this is what's going wrong if you can download the project from the website and try and test it in Safari you might know what goes wrong. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Feedback: if the code required for someone to run is on an external site and readers would need to download it in order to determine the issue, you have not supplied a [mcve]. We need everything to be in the question itself (though external code-runner sites are OK if they are merely an addendum).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that whenever I open this project in Dreamweaver it glitches for some peculiar reason, I just re-downloaded it and opened it in my other text editor and it worked perfectly.